# Generate C# using MSBuild

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, code-generation, msbuild-task

I have a batch file which generates a cs file. The new cs file is stored inside one of my projects solution.

Here is a snippet of my msbuild task:

```
<Target Name="MyDummyGenerator" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Generating file" />
    <Exec Command="./path_to_batch_file/dummy.bat" ContinueOnError="false" />
</Target>
```

The problem is that my generated file is not listed in the files to compile and is not a part of the assembly. After trying to add this file implicitly to the csproj file using `<Compile Include="MyGeneratedFile.cs">` I got this error (MyGeneratedFile.cs is the file written from the batch file:
"***Duplicate 'Content' items were included. The .NET SDK includes 'Content' items from your project directory by default***".

BTW - When compiling it again the generate file is a part of the assembly but it is because the file is in the project source before start the entire build step...

I even tried to run it in the PreBuild event with no luck.

What is the proper way of generating c# code using msbuild? 
P.S I'm using .net Framework 4.7.1

Comment: Which .NET framework you are using?

Comment: 4.7.1 (I will update the main post)

Comment: And can you add the batch file contents?

Comment: It just write a cs file content. For example
@@echo off
@@echo // Here is the C# file content for example > MyFile.cs

Answer (score 2):

I guess this post answer the question:
https://mhut.ch/journal/2015/06/30/build-time-code-generation-in-msbuild

In a nutshell, you need to hook the CoreCompile target to generate your file before compilation (or intellisense) starts and generate a Compile item inside a target.
See this doc for details on how to create items during build:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#create-items-during-execution

Also you should generate the file to the intermediate output (obj folder) rather than in your source to not mess up.
In the example below, the inputs and outputs are mainly here for MSBUILD to know what to refresh when files are changing.

```xml
<Target Name="UpdateGeneratedFiles"
  DependsOnTargets="_UpdateGeneratedFiles"
  Condition=="'@(ResourceFile)' != ''"
>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputDir)GeneratedFile.g.cs" />
    <!-- see https://mhut.ch/journal/2016/04/19/msbuild_code_generation_vs2015
    <FileWrites Include="$(IntermediateOutputDir)GeneratedFile.g.cs" />
    -->
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
<Target Name="_UpdateGeneratedFiles"
  Inputs="$(MSBuildProjectFile);@(ResourceFile)"
  Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputDir)GeneratedFile.g.cs"
>
  <FileGenerationTask
      Inputs="@(ResourceFile)"
      Output="$(IntermediateOutputDir)GeneratedFile.g.cs"
  >
</Target>
```

Comment: For me it is $(IntermediateOutputPath), not $(IntermediateOutputDir).